# how do i fill NaNs or Null values in a pandas dataframe with a mapping?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my data:

I have some missing values for continent. In Excel, I would use a vlookup to a table; how do I replicate that idea in pandas? Thanks!

```
pd.DataFrame([
    ["North America", "Canada"],
    [None, "Canada"],
    [None, "Canada"],
    [None, "Nigeria"],
    ["Africa", "Nigeria"],
], columns=["continent", "country"])
```

Comment: `df['continent'] = df.groupby('country')['continent'].transform('first')`

Comment: That worked great, thanks! Will have to learn more about the transform function.